# Fine Uploader to S3 bucket getting 405 Method Not Allowed error

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-s3, fine-uploader, http-status-code-405

I have been banging my head against the wall on this and am entirely stumped. I am trying to use FineUploader to upload files directly to my Amazon S3 bucket. I have essentially copied the code from the fineuploader.com web page (Upload Files Directly to Amazon S3) and the server-side PHP.

When I attempt to upload a file I see the post to the signature endpoint seems to work successfully but when it attempts to upload to S3 I get a 405 "Method Not Allowed" error.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head >
    <meta charset = "utf-8" >
    <link href = "http://fineuploader.com/source/fineuploader-3.9.1.min.css" rel = "stylesheet" >
</head >
<body >
<div id = "fine-uploader" ></div >

<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" ></script >
<script src = "js/uploader.js" ></script >
<script >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#fine-uploader").fineUploaderS3({
            debug: true,
            request: {
                endpoint: 'upload.roughdrag.com',
                accessKey: 'AKIAJL37USSCV......'
            },

            signature: {
                endpoint: 'handlers/uploadHandler.php'
            },
            uploadSuccess: {
                endpoint: 'index.php'
            },
            iframeSupport: {
                localBlankPagePath: 'blank.html'
            },
            retry: {
                enableAuto: true // defaults to false
            },

            paste: {
                targetElement: $(document),
                promptForName: true
            },

            deleteFile: {
                enabled: true,
                endpoint: 'handlers/uploadHandler.php'
            }
        });
    });
</script >
</body >
</html >
```

**PHP Signature Endpoint - uploadHandler.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * PHP Server-Side Example for Fine Uploader S3.
 * Maintained by Widen Enterprises.
 *
 * Note: This is the exact server-side code used by the S3 example
 * on fineuploader.com.
 *
 * This example:
 *  - handles both CORS and non-CORS environments
 *  - handles delete file requests for both DELETE and POST methods
 *  - Performs basic inspections on the policy documents and REST headers before signing them
 *  - Ensures again the file size does not exceed the max (after file is in S3)
 *  - signs policy documents (simple uploads) and REST requests
 *    (chunked/multipart uploads)
 *
 * Requirements:
 *  - PHP 5.3 or newer
 *  - Amazon PHP SDK (only if utilizing the AWS SDK for deleting files or otherwise examining them)
 *
 * If you need to install the AWS SDK, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/installation.html.
 */

// You can remove these two lines if you are not using Fine Uploader's
// delete file feature
require('../../includes/functions.php');
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// These assume you have the associated AWS keys stored in
// the associated system environment variables
$clientPrivateKey = '{removed}';
// These two keys are only needed if the delete file feature is enabled
// or if you are, for example, confirming the file size in a successEndpoint
// handler via S3's SDK, as we are doing in this example.
$serverPublicKey = '{removed}';
$serverPrivateKey = '{removed}';

// The following variables are used when validating the policy document
// sent by the uploader:
$expectedBucketName = "upload.roughdrag.com";
// $expectedMaxSize is the value you set the sizeLimit property of the
// validation option. We assume it is `null` here. If you are performing
// validation, then change this to match the integer value you specified
// otherwise your policy document will be invalid.
// http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/develop/api/options.html#validation-option
//$expectedMaxSize = 5000000;

$method = getRequestMethod();

// This first conditional will only ever evaluate to true in a
// CORS environment
if ($method == 'OPTIONS') {
    handlePreflight();
} // This second conditional will only ever evaluate to true if
// the delete file feature is enabled
else if ($method == "DELETE") {
    handleCorsRequest(); // only needed in a CORS environment
    deleteObject();
} // This is all you really need if not using the delete file feature
// and not working in a CORS environment
else if ($method == 'POST') {
    handleCorsRequest();

    // Assumes the successEndpoint has a parameter of "success" associated with it,
    // to allow the server to differentiate between a successEndpoint request
    // and other POST requests (all requests are sent to the same endpoint in this example).
    // This condition is not needed if you don't require a callback on upload success.
    if (isset($_REQUEST["success"])) {
        verifyFileInS3();
    } else {
        signRequest();
    }
}

// This will retrieve the "intended" request method.  Normally, this is the
// actual method of the request.  Sometimes, though, the intended request method
// must be hidden in the parameters of the request.  For example, when attempting to
// send a DELETE request in a cross-origin environment in IE9 or older, it is not
// possible to send a DELETE request.  So, we send a POST with the intended method,
// DELETE, in a "_method" parameter.
function getRequestMethod()
{
    global $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;

    // This should only evaluate to true if the Content-Type is undefined
    // or unrecognized, such as when XDomainRequest has been used to
    // send the request.
    if (isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
        parse_str($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, $_POST);
    }

    if ($_POST['_method'] != null) {
        return $_POST['_method'];
    }

    return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
}

// Only needed in cross-origin setups
function handleCorsRequest()
{
    // If you are relying on CORS, you will need to adjust the allowed domain here.
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.roughdrag.com');
}

// Only needed in cross-origin setups
function handlePreflight()
{
    handleCorsRequest();
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
}

function getS3Client()
{
    global $serverPublicKey, $serverPrivateKey;

    return S3Client::factory(array(
        'key' => $serverPublicKey,
        'secret' => $serverPrivateKey
    ));
}

// Only needed if the delete file feature is enabled
function deleteObject()
{
    getS3Client()->deleteObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $_POST['bucket'],
        'Key' => $_POST['key']
    ));
}

function signRequest()
{
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $responseBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $contentAsObject = json_decode($responseBody, true);
    $jsonContent = json_encode($contentAsObject);

    $headersStr = $contentAsObject["headers"];
    if ($headersStr) {
        signRestRequest($headersStr);
    } else {
        signPolicy($jsonContent);
    }
}

function signRestRequest($headersStr)
{
    if (isValidRestRequest($headersStr)) {
        $response = array('signature' => sign($headersStr));
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("invalid" => true));
    }
}

function isValidRestRequest($headersStr)
{
    global $expectedBucketName;

    $pattern = "/\/$expectedBucketName\/.+$/";
    preg_match($pattern, $headersStr, $matches);

    return count($matches) > 0;
}

function signPolicy($policyStr)
{
    $policyObj = json_decode($policyStr, true);

    if (isPolicyValid($policyObj)) {
        $encodedPolicy = base64_encode($policyStr);
        $response = array('policy' => $encodedPolicy, 'signature' => sign($encodedPolicy));
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("invalid" => true));
    }
}

function isPolicyValid($policy)
{
    global $expectedMaxSize, $expectedBucketName;

    $conditions = $policy["conditions"];
    $bucket = null;
    $parsedMaxSize = null;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($conditions); ++$i) {
        $condition = $conditions[$i];

        if (isset($condition["bucket"])) {
            $bucket = $condition["bucket"];
        } else if (isset($condition[0]) && $condition[0] == "content-length-range") {
            $parsedMaxSize = $condition[2];
        }
    }

    return $bucket == $expectedBucketName && $parsedMaxSize == (string)$expectedMaxSize;
}

function sign($stringToSign)
{
    global $clientPrivateKey;

    return base64_encode(hash_hmac(
        'sha1',
        $stringToSign,
        $clientPrivateKey,
        true
    ));
}

// This is not needed if you don't require a callback on upload success.
function verifyFileInS3()
{
    global $expectedMaxSize;

    $bucket = $_POST["bucket"];
    $key = $_POST["key"];

    // If utilizing CORS, we return a 200 response with the error message in the body
    // to ensure Fine Uploader can parse the error message in IE9 and IE8,
    // since XDomainRequest is used on those browsers for CORS requests.  XDomainRequest
    // does not allow access to the response body for non-success responses.
    if (getObjectSize($bucket, $key) > $expectedMaxSize) {
        // You can safely uncomment this next line if you are not depending on CORS
        //header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
        deleteObject();
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "Your file is too big!"));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("tempLink" => getTempLink($bucket, $key)));
    }
}

// Provide a time-bombed public link to the file.
function getTempLink($bucket, $key)
{
    $client = getS3Client();
    $url = "{$bucket}/{$key}";
    $request = $client->get($url);

    return $client->createPresignedUrl($request, '+15 minutes');
}

function getObjectSize($bucket, $key)
{
    $objInfo = getS3Client()->headObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key' => $key
    ));
    return $objInfo['ContentLength'];
}

?>
```

**Amazon S3 CORS Configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

**IAM Group Security Policy**

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
     "Effect":"Allow",
     "Action":"s3:PutObject",
     "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::upload.roughdrag.com/*"
   }]
}
```

**uploader.js was captured from http://fineuploader.com/source/all.fineuploader-3.9.1.min.js**

**Console response**

```
[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Grabbed 1 dropped files.

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Received 1 files or inputs.

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Submitting S3 signature request for 0

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending POST request for 0

POST http://www.roughdrag.com/handlers/uploadHandler.php  200 OK 195ms  

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending upload request for 0

POST http://upload.roughdrag.com/  405 Method Not Allowed 559ms 

"NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://upload.roughdrag.com/"

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Received response status 405 with body: <html>
<head><title>405 Method Not Allowed</title></head>
<body>
<h1>405 Method Not Allowed</h1>
<ul>
<li>Code: MethodNotAllowed</li>
<li>Message: The specified method is not allowed against this resource.</li>
<li>ResourceType: OBJECT</li>
<li>Method: POST</li>
<li>RequestId: 3493FE605B461EAF</li>
<li>HostId: HDXmtSpHufy6LDIH1Nsp0oYkLDvTC3XKFRRIadw66gmaMsF53Z3WYsCWooOoRcw2</li>
</ul>
<hr/>
</body>
</html>

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Waiting 5 seconds before retrying breakout.jpg...

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Detected valid cancel, retry, or delete click event on file 'breakout.jpg', ID: 0.

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Cancelling 0
```

The software looks amazing but I just can't get past this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a DNS issue created when you mapped your custom domain name to your S3 bucket.  After resolving upload.roughdrag.com, it looks like you have mapped this CNAME to "upload.roughdrag.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com".  Try mapping that CNAME to "upload.roughdrag.com.s3.amazaonaws.com" instead.

**Update 1:**

If you are still seeing issues after this change, I would post in the [AWS S3 forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=24).  Hopefully an employee will answer.  There may be an issue with your bucket/CNAME that I cannot see from my end.  It looks like a POST request to upload.roughdrag.com.s3.amazonaws.com goes though, but there are issues sending a POST request to upload.roughdrag.com.  I verified this with [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en).

**Update 2:**

With your latest CNAME change, it looks like POST requests are being accepted by S3.

Comment: That was the problem, Ray. The bucket properties for "static website hosting" specify the endpoint as upload.roughdrag.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com but as soon as I changed it to upload.roughdrag.com.s3.amazonaws.com this started working for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm having a very similar situation to the original poster.  Can you share your DNS settings for me?  And, are you using Amazon for the DNS?  I'm just mapping `uploads.mydomain.com` to my bucket's endpoint `BUCKETNAME.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: "After resolving upload.roughdrag.com, it looks like you have mapped this CNAME to "upload.roughdrag.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com". Try mapping that CNAME to "upload.roughdrag.com.s3.amazaonaws.com" instead" - worked for me

Comment: Be careful of that typo, should be: s3.amazonaws.com not s3.amazaonaws.com

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Fixed it by adding the region to the function below:

```
function getS3Client() {
    global $serverPublicKey, $serverPrivateKey;

    return S3Client::factory(array(
        'key' => $serverPublicKey,
        'secret' => $serverPrivateKey,
        'region' => 'ap-southeast-2'  //Revomve from non Sydney bucket
    ));
}
```

Find the region of your bucket by clicking on properties. Then Static website hosting and only take the details from the endpoint from ap-xxxxx-x